# Testing A component Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I have a class that looks like this which is component used in my app

```
@Component
public class SecurityUtility {

    private final String SALT = "salt";

    Random random;


    public SecurityUtility(Random random) {
        this.random = random;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12, new SecureRandom(SALT.getBytes()));
    }

    public String randomPassword() {
        String SALTCHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();

         while (stringBuilder.length() < 18) {
            int index =   rnd.nextInt() * SALTCHARS.length();
            stringBuilder.append(SALTCHARS.charAt(index));
        }
        String randPass = stringBuilder.toString();

        return randPass;
    }
}
```

What can I do to test such a class and how do I go about it , normally I have been doing unit tests but this class , don't know what type of test or how to go about it . Thank you in advance for any suggestion. Unit or any other test.

Testing with a fixed seed

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SecurityUtility.class)
public class SecurityUtilityTest {

    @MockBean
    Random random;

    @Test
    public void createRandomPasswordSeed() {

          random = new Random(1 );

        String randomPassword = new SecurityUtility(random).randomPassword();

        Assert.assertEquals("seed = 1" , "83T81EOKK3ZZB259U5" , randomPassword );
    }
```

error

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: seed = 1 
Expected :83T81EOKK3ZZB259U5
Actual   :Z49G2RLF0HJNNWZQCP

Comment: Don't you use the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` class of Spring here ?

Comment: yes I do, I guess the question is how to test this class , I will update the question @davidxxx

Comment: But generally you don't want to test trustworthy third party classes. What you could test here is randomPassword().

Comment: yeah you mean BCryptPasswordEncoder class is a standard third party class and should need no test, but what can I do for the randomPasswordTest, test if the class returns a random string ? how would that , especially , when using Assert

Comment: Well, call the method, and test that it does what it's supposed to do. But you have other problems here: 1. Why do you annotate your methods with `@Bean`? It makes no sense. 2. Why do you name your variables salt and saltStr, since they're not salts. 3. Why use nextFloat() instead of nextInt()? 4. This is supposed to be secure, so use a SecureRandom. 5. Why name SALT what is actually a seed, and why use a seed in the first place?

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the advice I will change my variables name and edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what can I do for the `randomPasswordTest`, test if the class returns a random string ?

You have to remove the randomness.

Best way to do that is to pass in the instance of class `Random` via *dependency injection*. Then you could pass in a *test double* of type Random for your tests.

This *test double* might be a *mock* created with a mocking framework.

On the other hand Javas `Random` class is a *pseudo random generator*.
That means starting with a fix *seed* it will always produce the same number sequence. So you can simply create an instance of  `Random` with a fix seed as your *test double*:

```
Random predictableValueProducer= new Random(1);
```

You can use a different seed in another test method and check the changed output to assure that your code really uses the `Random` object passed in.

---

> i don't know how to go about it, can you show how it should look like ?

code under test

```
@Component
public class SecurityUtility {
    private final String SALT = "salt";
    private final Random random;

    // I prefer constructor injection...
    public SecurityUtility(@Inject Random random){
         this.random = random ;
    }
    @Bean
    public String randomPassword() {
        String SALTCHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder salt = new StringBuilder();        
        while (salt.length() < 18) {
            int index = random.nextInt(SALTCHARS.length());
            salt.append(SALTCHARS.charAt(index));
        }
        return  salt.toString();
    }
}
```

test

```
public class SecurityUtilityTest {

    @Test
    public void createsRandomPasswordWithSeed1() {
        // arrange
        Random randomWithFixSeed = new Random(1);

        // act
        String randomPassword = 
           new SecurityUtility(randomWithFixSeed).randomPassword();

        // assert
        assertEquals("seed = 1", "83T81EOKK3ZZB2S9U5", randomPassword);
    }

    @Test
    public void createsRandomPasswordWithSeed2() {
        Random randomWithFixSeed = new Random(2);

        String randomPassword = 
           new SecurityUtility(randomWithFixSeed).randomPassword();

        assertEquals("seed = 2", "EYUT8GG2HYCC95OIH2", randomPassword);
    }
}
```

---

> for some reason they are not fixed

The test still fails because you did not complete the changes needed in the Code under Test. It still creates a new `Random` object inside  `randomPassword()` instead of using the member variable you introduced.

Remove this line:

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
```

and change this:

```
        //int index =   rnd.nextInt() * SALTCHARS.length();
        int index =   random.nextInt() * SALTCHARS.length();
```

Also you missuse `random.nextInt()` It should be

```
        int index =   random.nextInt(SALTCHARS.length());
```

as I already suggested.

> I tried to use the annotation @inject it came from dozer library and did not work , what library does that annotation belong to [...] I tried to use @Autowire but it shows no bean of type random – valik

The annotations have nothing to do with testing problem. They come into play at your applications runtime at the initialization phase.

Comment: i don't know how to go about it, can you show how it should look like ? @Timothy Truckle

Comment: for some reason they are not fixed i updated code u can see

Comment: @valik I mean the new version of `SecurityUtility`.

Comment: ok I have updated my securityUtility class check @Timothy Truckle

Comment: @valik your CUT still uses a new instance of Random and not the injected.

Comment: I tried to use the annotation @inject  it came from  dozer library and did not work , what library does that annotation belong to

Comment: I tried to use @Autowire but it shows no bean of type random

Comment: Hi @Timothy Truckle this is what it looks like now ? it  did not inject. reason we cannot inject something we don't have a bean for , I am still stuck on how to go about the test but I have autowired

Comment: @valik *"I tried to use `@Autowire` but it shows no bean of type random"* this is a different question, so create a new one.